# Why the output is not correct if the same characters are not adjacent?

Tags: javascript

An isogram is a word that has no repeating letters, consecutive or non-consecutive. Implement a function that determines whether a string that contains only letters is an isogram. Assume the empty string is an isogram. Ignore letter case.

```
function isIsogram(str){
  let NewStr = str.toLowerCase();
     for ( let i = 0; i < NewStr.length; i++){
        for ( let j = i + 1; j < NewStr.length; j++) {
            if ( NewStr[i] === NewStr[j]) {
                return false } 
            else {
                return true}
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: whta problem do you have with the given code?

Comment: In particular, if this gives an incorrect result for some specific input, it would be *really* useful if you'd specify that input, the result of this code, and the result you expected.

Comment: you return true if the first test is OK ... so you only ever test the first 2 letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will return `true` as soon as it finds two letters that are not equal:

```
if ( NewStr[i] === NewStr[j]) {
    return false } 
else {
    return true}
```

What you should do is return `false` only if the condition passes. If not continue the loop, and return `true` at the end:

```js
function isIsogram(str) {
  let NewStr = str.toLowerCase();
  for (let i = 0; i < NewStr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < NewStr.length; j++) {
      if (NewStr[i] === NewStr[j]) {
        return false
      }
    }
  }
  
  return true;
}

console.log(isIsogram('cdba')); // true
console.log(isIsogram('aa')); // false
console.log(isIsogram('efgaba')); // false
```

You can also do the same check using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). If the number of letters in the Set is equal to the number of letters in the original string, all characters are unique.

```js
function isIsogram(str) {
  return new Set(str.toLowerCase()).size === str.length;
}

console.log(isIsogram('cdba')); // true
console.log(isIsogram('aa')); // false
console.log(isIsogram('efgaba')); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

look what did your code do:

```
 if ( NewStr[i] === NewStr[j]) {
                return false } 
            else {
                return true}}
```

When the condition is true, return `false`, otherwise return `true`.
It means that function will be finished at the first time whether `NewStr[0] === NewStr[0]` is true or not

Answer (score 1):

What you can do:

1. Store a seen letter. If you have seen a letter before return `false`.
2. Use an object for for storing a seel letter, because if unseen, the property returns `false`
3. Use only a single loop.

Conclusion:

```js
function isIso(string) {
    var seen = {},
        i;
    
    string = string.toLowerCase();
    for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        if (seen[string[i]]) return false;
        seen[string[i]] = true;    
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(isIso(''));     // true
console.log(isIso('abc'));  // true
console.log(isIso('abbc')); // false
console.log(isIso('abca')); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Modern javascript code is simple as

```js
function isIsogram(str){
  return str.length === new Set(str.toLowerCase().split('')).size;
}
console.log(isIsogram('abcd'))
console.log(isIsogram('abcb'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isIsogram(str){
    for(let i=0; i<str.length; i++){
        if(str[i] === str[i+1]){ 
            return false
        }   
     }  
   return true 
  }
```